# Internal Server error 500 for .htaccess file create

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I create `.htaccess` file for urlrewrite. I get Internal Server Error 500. I've tried all the solutions from internet but it didn't work. File content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: You're going to need to show us what's the in file, and ideally what's in the Apache error log.

Comment: At least post the content of your .htaccess file

Comment: please post the content of your .htaccess file so that we can check what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way for you, is to try and create a new **.htaccess** file, since you didn't provide your **.htaccess** code, you can use [this site to generate a new htaccess file](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/)

please try posting your **.htaccess** file code, so we can know what's the problem

> remove the **//** after you generate the file, cause it's not the way to comment in .htaccess, it gave me Internal Server error 500.. Maybe that's why you have the error? i guess you commented with **//** instead of **#**